# How to sort by most recent date given additional ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in SQL Workbench (MySQL Workbench) like the following:

```
Customer_id || Rep_id || Date_of_service
        111 ||    654 || 1/1/2017
        111 ||    673 || 10/20/2018
        112 ||    655 || 1/1/2017
        112 ||    655 || 4/1/2018
        112 ||    654 || 5/10/2018
```

And I want the following back a list of unique customer_ids with most frequent rep_ids and in the case of a tie, most recent rep_id. Example:

```
Customer_id || Rep_id || Date_of_service
        111 ||    673 || 10/20/2018
        112 ||    655 || 4/1/2018
```

I tried the following code:

```
create table most_recent_rep as
select customer_id, rep_id, max(date_of_service) as most_recent_date from my_table
group by customer_id, rep_id;
```

But this did not give me a list of unique customer IDs. I also tried

```
create table most_recent_rep as
select customer_id, rep_id, date_of_service from 
(select customer_id, max(date_of_service) as most_recent_date from my_table) as b
on b.customer_id = a.customer_id and b.most_recent_date = a.date_of_service;
```

But this created fewer results than I know there to be.

Comment: Presumably dates are in fact using a suitable date data type?

Comment: Yes they are in a suitable date data type

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.date_of_service = (select max(t2.date_of_service)
                           from my_table t2
                           where t2.customer_id = t.customer_id
                          );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(customer_id, date_of_service)`.

Comment: This does not return a full list of customer IDs. I know that I have 400k eligible unique customers, but this returns only 100k.

Comment: @brightman1309 . . . This would only miss customers where all values of `date_of_service` are `NULL` or `customer_id` is `NULL`.